Python/Oct2Py/Octave Setup Woes
In Windows 10 or 11, I am trying to set up a Python/Oct2Py/Octave environment so that I can write Python scripts that can invoke Octave functionality. I set this up on my own machine, and got it working about a year ago. Now I am trying to replicate this setup, but my notes must be somewhat deficient, as I run into errors doing the simplest tasks. For example, in the Octave CLI, I can run this command:
octave:1> pwd()
ans = C:\Users\bob

In my working Anaconda Powershell, I can run this equivalent:
(base) PS C:\Users\bob> python
Python 3.9.12 (main, Apr  4 2022, 05:23:19) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from oct2py import Oct2Py
>>> o = Oct2Py()
>>> o.pwd()
'C:\\Users\\bob'
>>>

However, in my new setup, I run into problems:
(base) PS C:\Users\rsg> python
Python 3.9.12 (main, Apr  4 2022, 05:23:19) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from oct2py import Oct2Py
>>> o = Oct2Py()
>>> o.pwd()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\oct2py\dynamic.py", line 111, in __call__
    return self._ref().feval(self.name, *inputs, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\oct2py\core.py", line 403, in feval
    return self._feval(
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\oct2py\core.py", line 620, in _feval
    write_file(req, out_file, oned_as=self._oned_as, 
convert_to_float=self.convert_to_float)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\oct2py\io.py", line 58, in write_file
    data = _encode(obj, convert_to_float)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\oct2py\io.py", line 351, in _encode
    out[key] = _encode(value, ctf)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\oct2py\io.py", line 376, in _encode
    if isinstance(data, spmatrix):
NameError: name 'spmatrix' is not defined
>>>

In both cases, all the software is the same:

Windows 11 Home
Anaconda (2022.05 - Python 3.9.12)
Oct2Py (installed via "conda install -c conda-forge oct2py")
Octave 8.2.0

I cannot figure out what is going on with the new install (I've tried it on three separate machines, and they all fail).

can you share conda list output of both setups? Is scipy installed in both envs? If not, install it and check again. ALso try from scipy.sparse import spmatrix in your new setup

The "from scipy" idea did not help; I add that when I import Oct2Py and get the exact same error traceback. Also, other than a few minor differences in versions, the conda list command gives the same output; the closest differences that could be related is that the working setup has oct2py == 5.6.0 and octave_kernel == 0.35.1, and the non-working setup has oct2py == 5.7.2 and octave_kernel == 0.36.0.  I would not expect that to be the issue here.

I have figured out a workaround, which I post here for posterity. In the Oct2Py module io.py, there are these two lines within the _encode() function:
if isinstance(data, spmatrix):
    return data.astype(np.float64)

If I add this line:
from scipy.sparse import spmatrix  # type:ignore[import-untyped]

before those, the error is avoided. I don't really understand why, though, as that line is invoked when the module is loaded (I added a print debug message and it sure enough gets executed). Note that this is for Oct2Py v5.7.2, where the older v5.6.0 has the same code, yet does not throw the exception!
